# cURL returns weird characters like "ďťż "

Tags: php, curl

My website generates a xml file with products and stocks. I've written a php file on my site hosting and I wanted to use cURL to extract some data and send it to a third party.

My php code is:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://path_to_my_xml_file',
));
$header = array('Accept-Charset: UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump ($resp);
curl_close($curl);
```

But my var dump gets an:

**string(14939) "ďťż** " on Chrome and  **string(14939) "ï»¿ "** on Firefox

Also, if I run the php file on my computer (XAMPP) it returns the correct values.

Comment: `ï»¿` would be a BOM. _“Also, if I run the php file on my computer (XAMPP) it returns the correct values.”_ - well then most likely the character encoding used (/indicated to the client) by your local script is a different one, then on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)?

A example code:

```
<?php
// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `curl_getinfo`? You've posted a snippet that doesn't contain a call to that method

Comment: Sorry I forget the call to curl_getinfo.

Comment: And how does this solve the problem? You are only checking for more errors, but this code won't help to remove them

Comment: Well, the answer has few information, he can get more data with this code.